# How to get rid of the "red zone" in table?

Tags: html, css

```css
div {
  display: table;
  width: 900px;
}

input {
  width: calc(100% - 10px);
  display: table-cell;
}

section {
  display: table-cell;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input>
  <section><button>+ invite</button></section>
</div>
```

I want `input` to fit all the place remaining. I am trying to use table to do that. But i can't get rid of the "red zone". It is unnecessary space, that i am trying to get rid of.

I want input to be wider so that there was no "red zone".

**IMPORTANT**: set width 100% to button is not a right solution.

here is code pen link https://codepen.io/CitizenOne/pen/QegBjQ

Comment: Hi ! Can you please tell why adding `width: 100%` to `button` is not right?

Comment: can you use flexbox?

Comment: @Allan Jebaraj cause in my real website the button should have as as small a width as possible. In my real site the width of the button is depends only on text in the button and paddings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use the table layout model. Flexbox is far more powerful and better suited to this.

`<section>` doesn't appear to have the right semantics for this content either, so I got rid of it.

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  outline: dotted black 5px;
  width: 500px; /* Reduced width to make it clearer in the small demo window */
}

input {
  flex: 1; 
  background: #afa;
  margin-right: 25px;
}

button {
  flex: 0;
  background: #faa;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input>
  <button>+ invite</button>
</div>
```

Comment: but there is no space between input and section

Comment: @JackShcherbakov — So add a margin

Comment: I tried to use width calc(100% - 10px). Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Add width to button.

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 900px;
}

input {
  width: calc(100% - 67px);
}

section {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div>
    
  <input>
  <button>+ invite</button>
  
</div>
```

Comment: no, it is not what i want. In my website this solution can't be used

Comment: @JackShcherbakov i have modified answer and fix the width using calc you dont need to use display table for this.